# Induction proof harmonic series

Tags: induction

> Prove that $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}>\ln n$$

The base case is trivial, but I cannot show it holds for $n+1$ if it does for $n$ :/

Comment: Hint: The Mean Value Theorem shows that $1/(n+1)\le\log(n+1)-\log(n)\le1/n$.

Comment: Hint : Compare the areas of some specific staircase function and the $\frac{1}{x}$-function from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: I know that proof using MVT but this is supposed to be solved without "advanced" results, just with induction and basic calculus

Comment: What calculus _are_ you allowed to use? (I can't think of anything more "basic" than MVT; in particular, for example, without MVT you have no Fundamental Theorem...)

Comment: No, it has to be done without integrals,derivatives,etc. Also, that question is different.

Comment: Well, real numbers axioms, basically its meant to be solved with induction.

Comment: If you're  not allowed to use calculus at all, then what is your definition of $\ \ln\ ?$